# how to apply css to web app?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari

I am experiencing problem with scc style do not apply when I adding my web app to a home screen of iphone and lunching app with shortcut(icon). So here is two examples. First open with safari.

[image]

here is the screenshot of same web opened with icon in iphone menu

[image]

So for some reason the css style do not apply for Melanie Wright on the second image and also icons for input fields still white not orange, if I open this web app with shortcut(icon). 
here is my meta tags that I used to mimic the look like it is app

```
<!-- Iphone Icon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

Thank you for you time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers tend to cache css and script resources for a period of time. 
Try clearing out the cache on the device or even manually force it to load a new file.  Its a good way to know that you are not using a cache version of the css file.

Just add ?v=1 to the end of your file.

```
    script.js?v=1
```